# MySQL Display rows from and To

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have a book in a database and I want to display pages from and to. For example

From Page 5 to Page 7..

How would I do this? Right now I am able to get pages From only:

For ex;

```
$getPages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  book WHERE pags='5'") or die(mysql_error());

while($rowPages = mysql_fetch_array($getPages)) {

$page = $rowAR['pageText'];
echo $page;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$getPages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  book WHERE pags>='5' AND pags<='7'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your db table consists of one page per row:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE page BETWEEN 5 AND 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIMIT command of MYSQL to return certain rows:

Ex.

SELECT * FROM books LIMIT 15, 30

This script returns the first 30 rows after row 15 in the books table.

Other sample:
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15